# What do I need to know on NLP to be able to use and train Stanford NLP for intent analysis?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Any books, tutorials, course reccommedations would be much appreciated.

I need to know at what level I need to be regarding NLP to be able to comprehend the Stanford NLP and train it to customize it for my app of commercial sentiment analysis.

My goal is not a career in NLP or become an expert in NLP but only to be as much proficient to be able to understand and use the open source NLP frameworks properly and train them for my application.

For this level, what NLP study/training would be needed?

I'm learning c# and .net as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: to simply use a sentiment model or train on existing data, there is not too much background to learn:

- Tokenization
- Constituency parsing, parse trees, etc.
- Basic machine learning concepts (classification, cost functions, training / development sets, etc.)

These are well-documented ideas and are all a Google away. It might be worth it to skim the [Coursera Natural Language Processing course](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp) (produced by people here at Stanford!) for the above ideas as well.

After that, the significant task is understanding how the RNTN sentiment model inside CoreNLP works. You don't need to grasp the math fully, I suppose, but the basic recursive nature of the algorithm is important to understand. The best resource is of course the [original paper](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/) (and there's not much else, to be honest).

---

To train your own sentiment model, you'll need your own sentiment data. Producing this data is no small task. The data for the Stanford sentiment model was crowdsourced, and you may need to do something similar if you want to collect anything near the same scale.

The RNTN sentiment paper (linked above) gives some details on the data format. I'm happy to expand on this further if you do wish to create your own data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. What i want to build is an algorithm which can analyze twitter tweets data(thousands of tweets) for a particular keyword and analyze filter those tweets to find people of a specific intention. For example I want to feed the algorithm  10K tweets scraped for the keyword "NLP" from twitter and I want the algorithm to filter and give me the number of tweets that have the intention to "learn NLP"(No marketing msgs, actual users). I do not have any background in NLP and learning programming. How do you recommend I should proceed? Learn Python and then the stanford cors?

Comment: Getting the data is not the problem. The problem is developing this algorithm from the ground up(using the open source NLP frameworks0 to filter the date for the above mentioned need is. Would the Python NLTK library enough for this or Stanford one is recommended? Would the above steps you mentioned the right way for the project I mentioned above?

Comment: the link that you mentioned has more of analysis about positive, negative or neutral sentiments about a certain thing. in this project,  the goal is not to find positive, negative or neutral. But the goal here is to mention a keyword and filter through the data to find a certain intent for the mentioned keyword in the data? The keyword queried can also be "learn nlp", "study nlp", etc. But the goal here is to filter the big data for advertisements and people mentioning those keywords for other reasons(eg. someone saying "study nlp" to someone, we dont want this)discover actual users.

Comment: maybe the project more about IR(Information retrieval) than sentiment analysis. The learning for this should also be proceeded in the way you mentioned?

Comment: A nice start is the free online [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/). This is a gentle introduction to NLP concepts in Python using the NLTK toolkit. Re: your 'intent analysis' application, this is not at all an easy problem. You need to formalize the concept of an 'intent,' and develop a novel algorithm for extracting this kind of information from surface text. A more doable goal would be to pick out explicitly stated intents (like literal statements of "learn NLP") along with their subject / object arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding --> "formalize the concept of an 'intent,' and develop a novel algorithm for extracting this kind of information from surface text." ; can you outline what would be the steps to do it using different parts of NLP? Would i would like the algorithm to know is different kind of words like "learn", "study", "research" etc and for it to be able to identify the was a normal user would use them for "NLP" or "machine learning" or anything else. And what part of NLP should be used(Step wise) to construct the algorithm to extract this kind of information?

Comment: also can this be accomplished with nltk or would need the stanford library?

Comment: NLTK is much easier to learn, but CoreNLP is much more powerful. (Disclaimer: I am a CoreNLP developer :) )

Comment: This really isn't the best to explain in full (i.e., in Stack Overflow comments). If you post new SO questions for your various issues you should get much better feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply comprehend the concept of supervised learning, unsupervised learning. In addition, some Java knowledge might be useful.